# How to print tiny BMP in a small section of a 320x200 screen without affecting the existing picture already on the screen

Tags: x86, bmp, palette

For a project I am able to print a small BMP (40x30 pixels) but it is being painted with the whole 320x200 pixels as well (with some background color taken from the BMP Palette). 
Can I just put a small BMP on the screen in a limited area without affecting an exiting picture that is already there? 16 bit TASM 8086.

Comment: Yes, sure, just copy each row from the BMP to the corresponding part of a row of VGA memory.  The rectangle you're writing is part of a larger image, so the stride between rows is 320 pixels, different from the width of the rectangle you want to store.

Comment: Hi Peter , apparently I can put my small BMP where I need but I see left over pixels that are placed all over the remaining pixels. I need an overlay feature that should not destroy the whole picture. Should I clear something prior putting this small BMP or change my VGA graphics mode from 0x13 ?

Comment: Ok, so don't modify pixels outside of the area where you want your BMP displayed.  If your code wasn't intentionally writing pixels outside that area, debug it so it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. I am not writing anything else intentionally to the screen memory. I am not aware who writes these pixels.

Comment: Use a debugger.  Set a watch-point on video RAM outside that square and see what's writing it.  e.g. QEMU+GDB or BOCHS with it's built-in debugger can probably do this.

Comment: Just an update : by altering the base address for the video from 0x0a000 to a larger number It helped me get rid of the unneeded parts I had seen on my screen.